# Distinct sql based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the table structure. Column one contains strings which might be present in more than one row. I want to write a query in such a way column1 value is only repeated once such that row where column2 contains A takes priority. If only B is available output the same.

Sample Data is provided below and expected sql output.

Table Structure (there are other columns as well which is skipped here)

```
Column1 Column2
 123       A
 234       A
 234       B
 435       A
 536       B
```

SQL Expected Output

```
Column1 Column2
 123       A
 234       A
 435       A
 536       B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Column1, MIN(Column2) AS Column2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY Column1;
```

[image]

### Demo

This should work because `MIN` would always select `A` over `B`, should both values be present.