# Distinct sql based on condition More than two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the table structure. Column one contains strings which might be present in more than one row. I want to write a query in such a way column1 value is only repeated once such that row where column2 contains A takes priority. If only B is available output the same. Also with this the related column3 needs to be printed. In cases where there are more than one row with same value in Column1 and Column2 pick any(Ex: row 2 and 3 in the below).

Sample Data is provided below and expected sql output.

Table Structure (there are other columns as well which is skipped here)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
 123       A       1
 234       A       1
 234       A       4
 234       B       2
 435       A       2
 536       B       1
```

SQL Expected Output

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
 123       A      1
 234       A      1
 435       A      2
 536       B      1
```

Note : This is an extension to this question [Distinct sql based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774245/distinct-sql-based-on-condition)

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql Version is 8.0

Comment: Column2 can only contain 'A' and 'B'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT   tab.Column1,
         tab.Column2,
         MIN(tab.Column3)
FROM     (SELECT Column1,
                 MIN(Column2) as min_column2
          FROM   tab
          GROUP BY Column1
         ) t
JOIN     tab
  ON     tab.Column1 = t.Column1
 AND     tab.Column2 = t.min_column2
GROUP BY tab.Column1,
         tab.Column2;
```

It's plain ANSI-SQL and doesn't depend on your DB or its version.

Answer (score 1):

Since your MySQL version is 8.0, we can utilize [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) functionality. We can determine `Row_Number()` values within a partition of a `Column1` values, with row number 1 corresponding to the minimum value of `Column2` in the partition. This will also handle the case when there are multiple rows with same minimum `Column2` value and it will pick any one of them.

Then we can use this result-set in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and get the rows where Row number is equal to 1.

```
SELECT
  dt.Column1, dt.Column2, dt.Column3
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    Column1, Column2, Column3, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 
                       ORDER BY Column2 ASC) AS rowno 
  FROM your_table
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.rowno = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a correlated subquery is the simplest approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.column2, t.column3) =
       (select column2, column3
        from t t2
        where t2.column1 = t.column1
        order by (column2 = 'A') desc  -- put "A" first
        limit 1
       );
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try

```
select distinct column1, column2, column3
from tableName
order by column1
```

I am sure it will be working.

Comment: Will return unwanted B rows.

Comment: Will also return duplicated records for 234-A